# AirPods Pro stuttering and glitches audio on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: sound, bluetooth, bluez

As the title says.
My hardware is DELL XPS 13 9380

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer 1435 Wireless-AC [1a56:143a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Audio profile is A2DP Sink

Comment: Try removing re-paring.

Comment: Already tried , did not solve it